# Why is there "httpd" on OS X and "apache" on Ubuntu?

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd

Why is there a difference in the name for the same thing on different OSes?

On OS X I have `httpd`. On Linux, `apache`.

```
ps aux | grep httpd
ps aux | grep apache
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apache` is a legacy name.

While originally it was used for the web server, "Apache" is now a [software foundation](http://apache.org/). From a historical perspective, the Apache group were the people involved with creating `httpd`. Since that was the first project, the HTTP server was often referred to as Apache.

These days there are [dozens of projects](http://projects.apache.org/indexes/alpha.html) under the Apache Software Foundation. Of course they are all named "Apache…", and the list of projects still includes the [Apache HTTP Server](http://projects.apache.org/projects/http_server.html).

See also: [Fixing confusion of Apache vs httpd](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-docs/201003.mbox/%3C4B92C085.2020601@rowe-clan.net%3E)

> Perhaps choosing the program's name to be the name of the foundation was
>   a mistake, but the least we can do is to help adjust for the reality of
>   the current structure and framework of our foundation.

And: [About the Apache HTTP Server Project – The Apache HTTP Server Project](http://httpd.apache.org/ABOUT_APACHE.html)